# Displaying selected data while Xml parsing in android

Tags: android, xml

```
public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

Boolean currentElement = false;
String currentValue = null;
public static SitesList sitesList = null;

public static SitesList getSitesList() {
    return sitesList;
}

public static void setSitesList(SitesList sitesList) {
    MyXMLHandler.sitesList = sitesList;
}

/** Called when tag starts ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
 * -- <name> )*/
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    currentElement = true;

    if (localName.equals("student_response"))
    {
        /** Start */
        sitesList = new SitesList();
        //sitesList.setquizno(currentValue);
    } 

}




/** Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
 * -- </name> )*/
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    currentElement = false;


    /** set value */

    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("quiz_one"))
    {

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("quiz_no"))
        sitesList.setquizno(currentValue);
    //if(Integer.parseInt(sitesList.getquizno().get(Integer.parseInt(currentValue)))==1)
    //{

    /*else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("subject"))
        sitesList.setsubject(currentValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("grade"))
        sitesList.setgrade(currentValue);
    else*/else  if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("question_no"))
        sitesList.setquestionno(currentValue);
     else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("question"))
            sitesList.setquestion(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("option1"))
            sitesList.setoption1(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("option2"))
            sitesList.setoption2(currentValue);
         else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("option3"))
                sitesList.setoption3(currentValue);
            else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("option4"))
                sitesList.setoption4(currentValue);
            /*else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("option5"))
                sitesList.setoption5(currentValue);*/
            else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("correct_answer"))
                sitesList.setcorrectans(currentValue);

            /*else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("explaination"))
                sitesList.setdescription(currentValue);
            else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("remark"))
                sitesList.setremark(currentValue);*/
    }
}




/** Called to get tag characters ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
 * -- to get AndroidPeople Character ) */
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    if (currentElement) {
        currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        currentElement = false;
    }

}
```

}

Using the above code i have parsed the xml file in android .

Following is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<student_response>

<info>

<quiz_one>
<quiz_no>1</quiz_no>
<subject>general</subject>
<grade>A</grade>

<all_question>
<question_frame>
<question_no>1</question_no>
<question>What is capital of india ?</question>
<option1>Delhi</option1>
<option2>Mumbai</option2>
<option3>Chennai</option3>
<option4>Benglore</option4>
<option5>Kolkata</option5>
<correct_answer>Delhi</correct_answer>
<explaination>Delhi is capital of india....</explaination>
<remark>capital of india </remark>
</question_frame>

<question_frame>
<question_no>2</question_no>
<question>Who is the founder of facebook ?</question>
<option1>James Goslings</option1>
<option2>Dennis Ritchie</option2>
<option3>Bjarne Stroustrup</option3>
<option4>Brian Kernighan's</option4>
<option5>Mark Zuckerberg</option5>
<correct_answer>Mark Zuckerberg</correct_answer>
<explaination>Mark Zuckerberg:facebook </explaination>
<remark>facebook</remark>
</question_frame>


<question_frame>
<question_no>3</question_no>
<question>Who is the current prime minister of india ?</question>
<option1>Pratibha patil</option1>
<option2>Dr. Manmohan singh</option2>
<option3>Rajiv Gandhi</option3>
<option4>Atal bihari vajpayee</option4>
<option5>Moraraji Desai</option5>
<correct_answer>Dr. Manmohan singh</correct_answer>
<explaination>Dr. Manmohan singh:current P.M. </explaination>
<remark>Prime Minister</remark>
</question_frame>

<question_frame>
<question_no>4</question_no>
<question>What does EPROM stand for?</question>
<option1>Electric Programmable Read Only Memory </option1>
<option2>Erasable Programmable Read Only Memory </option2>
<option3>Evaluable Philotic Random Optic Memory</option3>
<option4>Every Person Requires One Mind</option4>
<option5>Evaluable Philotic Random Optic Memory</option5>
<correct_answer>Erasable Programmable Read Only Memory </correct_answer>
<explaination>EPROM  stand for Erasable Programmable Read Only Memory </explaination>
<remark>EPROM</remark>
</question_frame>

<question_frame>
<question_no>5</question_no>
<question>Where is the headquarters of Microsoft located?</question>
<option1>Santa Clara, California </option1>
<option2>Tucson, Arizona </option2>
<option3>Richmond, Virginia </option3>
<option4>Redmond, Washington</option4>
<option5>Tucson, Arizona </option5>
<correct_answer>Santa Clara, California </correct_answer>
<explaination>headquarters of Microsoft : Santa Clara, California </explaination>
<remark>Microsoft</remark>
</question_frame>
</all_question>
</quiz_one>



<quiz_two>

<quiz_no>2 </quiz_no>
<subject>Other topic</subject>
<grade>A</grade>

<all_question>
<question_frame>
<question_no>1</question_no>
<question>Who is the current prime minister of india ?</question>
<option1>Pratibha patil</option1>
<option2>Dr. Manmohan singh</option2>
<option3>Rajiv Gandhi</option3>
<option4>Atal bihari vajpayee</option4>
<option5>Moraraji Desai</option5>
<correct_answer>Dr. Manmohan singh</correct_answer>
<explaination>Dr. Manmohan singh:current P.M. </explaination>
<remark>Prime Minister</remark>
</question_frame>

<question_frame>
<question_no>2</question_no>
<question>What does EPROM stand for?</question>
<option1>Electric Programmable Read Only Memory </option1>
<option2>Erasable Programmable Read Only Memory </option2>
<option3>Evaluable Philotic Random Optic Memory</option3>
<option4>Every Person Requires One Mind</option4>
<option5>Evaluable Philotic Random Optic Memory</option5>
<correct_answer>Erasable Programmable Read Only Memory </correct_answer>
<explaination>EPROM  stand for Erasable Programmable Read Only Memory </explaination>
<remark>EPROM</remark>
</question_frame>


<question_frame>
<question_no>3</question_no>
<question>Who is the founder of facebook ?</question>
<option1>James Goslings</option1>
<option2>Dennis Ritchie</option2>
<option3>Bjarne Stroustrup</option3>
<option4>Brian Kernighan's</option4>
<option5>Mark Zuckerberg</option5>
<correct_answer>Mark Zuckerberg</correct_answer>
<explaination>Mark Zuckerberg:facebook </explaination>
<remark>facebook</remark>
</question_frame>

<question_frame>
<question_no>4</question_no>
<question>Where is the headquarters of Microsoft located?</question>
<option1>Santa Clara, California </option1>
<option2>Tucson, Arizona </option2>
<option3>Richmond, Virginia </option3>
<option4>Redmond, Washington</option4>
<option5>Tucson, Arizona </option5>
<correct_answer>Santa Clara, California </correct_answer>
<explaination>headquarters of Microsoft : Santa Clara, California </explaination>
<remark>Microsoft</remark>
</question_frame>

<question_frame>
<question_no>5</question_no>
<question>What is capital of india ?</question>
<option1>Delhi</option1>
<option2>Mumbai</option2>
<option3>Chennai</option3>
<option4>Benglore</option4>
<option5>Kolkata</option5>
<correct_answer>Delhi</correct_answer>
<explaination>Delhi is capital of india....</explaination>
<remark>capital of india </remark>
</question_frame>
</all_question>


</quiz_two>

</info>
</student_response>
```

My Question is how to parse only 1 block of data from xml in android. Example from if i want to fetch only 1 quiz at time how i can do it.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

you can add elements to the Adapter of your list and run `getAdapter().notifyDatasetChanged()`, this will trigger the list refresh

Answer (score 0):

If we want to extract the data from a xml file once we have to move to SAX, which is one time top to bottom read approach and if we want ot randomly pick the data in an xml file then the tree reperesentation of DOM model is to be put into use.
You can use DOM Parser for your code. ok